# ¡Larguémonos (de aquí)!

Tags: gramática

¡Larguémonos (de aquí)! means "let's get out of here!", clear enough. It looks like larguemos + nos to me (Present Subjunctive of largar). Is there a rule about dropping s from emos in such a case? It looks quite natural, yet I can't find it.

Note, the question is about the removal of the S, which isn't the focus of the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Hi Alex, this is a good question indeed, but the title is a little hard to understand, can you modify it so the actual question reflects the description? thank you

Comment: Yes, it’s a euphony rule.

When the _nos_ reflexive pronoun is appended to a 1st-person plural imperative form (which would end in _-s_), that _-s_ is dropped before adding the pronoun: *dejémo**nos** de cuentos*. Curiously, the _-s_ is not dropped before other pronouns: *abandonémo**sles***.

Comment: not a duplicate, The OP is asking for the rules of  conjugations when the "S" of  mos  is dropped when we add the Nos 

ie: vamonos instead of vamosnos; alejemonos instead alejemosnos, anunciemonos instead of enunciemosnos , etc.

Comment: @mike the other Q may ask a different thing, but the answers explain exactly this.